# Reducing the column to one element?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I see a code like this:

```
boston=datasets.load_boston()
X=boston.data[:, None, 6]
y= boston.target
```

The site says "To match the X and y dimensionality the X is reduced to 1 element in each row, by the following code".  How is it 1 element? I am a total newbie in this field.

Thank You,
anita

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at X:

```
from sklearn import datasets

boston=datasets.load_boston()
X=boston.data[:, None, 6]
y= boston.target

X[:10]
```

It looks like this:

```
array([[ 65.2],
       [ 78.9],
       [ 61.1],
       [ 45.8],
       [ 54.2],
       [ 58.7],
       [ 66.6],
       [ 96.1],
       [100. ],
       [ 85.9]])
```

This is one element per row. Another way is to consider this from a data frame perspective.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df.head(10)

       0
0   65.2
1   78.9
2   61.1
3   45.8
4   54.2
5   58.7
6   66.6
7   96.1
8  100.0
9   85.9
```

Finally, one other way to visualize this is through Spyder's variable explorer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but can you help me with what the other parameters like None and 6 mean  in this:  X=boston.data[:, None, 6]

Comment: X needs to be of the shape (n, 1). Slicing with `None` creates a new axis. If you select `boston.data[:,6]`, you'll have your data, but it's in a shape of (501,). To solve this, we need a new axis, and we do this by slicing with `None`. That stacks the data into an (n,1) shape. In other words, this is a shortcut for `boston.data[:, 6].reshape(506,1)`